# Faking a file extension

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I am creating a an online HTML editor and I am wondering if it is possible to fake a file extension.

So what happens is a user can create a file and choose weather it should be a .html, .css, or a .js file then they would enter into a code editor what ever they wanted to be saved to a database.  The problem comes in the live preview feature I have.  Instead of creating files on the server I am just grabbing the code they wrote from a database so a url to access a users file would be something like http://novuta.com/p/files/code.php?watermelon=23  and it would pull the code from the database where there is an id of 23, pretty simple.

But... if the user creates a link between two files such as

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "http://www.novuta.com/p/files/code.php?watermelon=23">
```

the link will be fine but it would come across to the browser as plane text not a .css file.

I am not sure but there may be a way to salve this using .htaccess but the file would have the extension that the user chose.

This is my first question sorry if it wasn't the best

Comment: You don't need the correct file extension for your browser to interpret something correctly, you just need to send the correct response headers (specifically content-type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could just set proper `Content-Type` in your php file that renders css, as:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css"); 
header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
//your css code
?>
```

Comment: whut! So you can basically just have any PHP code in your "CSS" file? Like getting the background color out of the DB and so on?

Comment: @Mathlight its not PHP code in CSS file but the other way round.. You can add css code in PHP file and using Content-Type headers render the CSS

Comment: Alright. So you can have then something like this? `.content{ background-color: #<?php echo $css['contentBackground']; ?>` in an PHP file, but ALL browsers are thinking that you serve an `.css` file... Damm i'm gonna love this!

Comment: @Mathlight exactly.. :)